# How to align label and select in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following structure:

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label class="col-xs-11">Specimen
            <select class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let option of specimenOptions" [value]="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <i class="sprite sprite-Arrow-Right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-group label {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   font-weight: normal;
}

.form-group select {
   margin-left: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Is there any way to align the icon with the rest of the elements without specifying `margin-top` property ?

Comment: how  you create the icon? `<i class="sprite sprite-Arrow-Right" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it by using

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
```

on every element. I also put them all in a column and had to make your *select* independent from *label*. You can see the [result here](https://jsfiddle.net/hrx8wg01/1/). I hope it helps.